# Two angular2 services using same Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have two angular2 services, one providing data

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get('/api/foo')
        .map(res => new Data(res.json().data));
}
```

and one providing settings

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getSettings(): Observable<Settings> {
    return this.http.get('/api/foo')
        .map(res => new Settings(res.json().settings));
}
```

The response from /api/foo is

```
{
    "settings": {
        ...
    }
    "data": {
        ....
    }
}
```

These services both use the same api call to get their content and the call to the server is being made twice for the same data.

I realize that the existing api is not ideal in combining both data and settings in one message and may eventually need to be replaced.

In the meantime my question is: using the existing api is there a straightforward way to provide a data service and a settings service that share the same api call?  Can there be one call to the api delivering data to both services, or must each service operate independently?

**UPDATE:**
My thoughts so far are that I need to create a base service that makes the actual http call, call this FooService.  FooService then needs to be injected into both SettingsService and DataService who can then represent FooService's output as settings and data respectively.  Where I get stuck is how do I fork the `Observable<any>` returned by FooService into two other Observables, `Observeable<Data>` in Dataservice and `Observeable<Settings>` in SettingsService? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a way to dynamically select from an object by key. Is this what you are looking for?

```
public getSettings(dataKey): Observable<Settings> {
    return this.http.get('/api/foo')
        .map(res => new Settings(res.json()[dataKey]);
}
```

Comment: @'Simon H' - the code works fine at the moment, there is both a setting and a data property in the response and there is no need for dynamic selection.  My question is about how to refactor the design so that only one http call is made to get the data but two services are provided using that data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.  Create one service to access the api and then create the Settings and Data services using .map() on the api service.

First create the service that access the underlying api:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('/api/foo')
            .map(res => res.json()));
}
```

Then create the two services that the program will consume:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

    constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

    public getSettings(): Observable<Settings> {
        return this.api.getObservable()
            .map(res => new Settings(res.settings));
    }
}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

    public getData(): Observable<Data> {
        return this.api.getObservable()
            .map(res => new Data(res.data));
    }
}
```